# Javascript variable created during return function

Tags: javascript, function, rest, controller, server

I have a function that I don't quite understand. It is here:

```
function responseWithResult(res, statusCode) {
       statusCode = statusCode || 200;
       return function(entity) {
            if (entity) {
           res.status(statusCode).json(entity);
            }
          };
        }
```

This function gets passed res and statusCode variables but then upon return it seems to create this entity variable. The entity variable is not created anywhere outside of this function so how is it being created here? For full scope that project that uses this is here:

https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack

Comment: `responseWithResult()` returns a function (a closure to be exact), and functions have arguments. `entity` is the argument of the returned function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`responseWithResult()` returns a function when you call it.

When that returned function is then called at some later time, it should be passed the `entity` parameter by that caller.  Because of the closure, that internal function will then have access to `res`, `statusCode` and `entity`.  The first two were passed as arguments when `responseWithResult()` was called.  The last was passed as an argument when the returned function was called.

So, this would be used like this:

```
var fn = responseWithResult(res, someStatus);

// then some time later
fn(someEntityValue);
```

Comment: it makes so much sense. I feel like because i spent so much time looking at this function I forgot to see the big picture. Now that I just want to make sure I understand this. The return function gets passed the information from  the original caller and because it is nested inside of the the responseWithResult function it also has access to res and status code . In this case it would seem that res and entity are the same variable. Is this accurate?

Comment: @Luidelaparra - `res` and `entity` are different parameters.  Both are available inside the inner function.  In Javascript, an inner function automatic gets access to any variables in any parent scope.  They aren't 'passed" to the inner function, but are simply accessible in the function.  They are "in-scope".

Comment: Thank you. I guess passed is the wrong word to use. I meant to use accessible. The returned function can access those parameters. I do appreciate you answering my question. I don't want to take up much more of you time, but perhaps you can clarify the use on entity. If I call responseWithResult(res) responseWithResult sets statusCode then calls the return function passing in entity which I thought would be the res. Is this incorrect? Again thank you for your time.

Comment: @Luidelaparra - `responseWithResult()` does not call the inner function.  It returns that function as a return value.  The caller of `responseWithResult()` has to take that return value and then call that function itself (see the code in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Invoking responseWithResult returns a function which accepts entity as a parameter. Entity isn't created outside the function, it is the variable name assigned to the paramater the returned function is called with.

The reason this is done is because the returned function has access to statusCode and res via a closure.

You would call this function like this:

```
responseWithResult('foo', 'bar')('baz');
```

Or like this:

```
var fn = responseWithResult('foo', 'bar');
fn('baz');
```